# Android - Saving an IMG and displaying in new layout

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I am a beginner in android and I'm trying to make an application that takes a photograph (using intents) with the first layout, and displays it on a second layout.

If I don't change the layout, I can display the picture. But I want the taken picture to display on a brand new layout. I am currently using this, trying to bring it to my share layout but that is not working.

```
    if(requestCode == CAM_REQUEST){
        setContentView(R.layout.share);
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imgTakenPhoto.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
    }
```

I followed a tutorial I found on youtube.
Here is my mainAcitivty code:

(imports)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    ImageButton btnTakePhoto;
    ImageView imgTakenPhoto;
    private static final int CAM_REQUEST = 1313;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnTakePhoto = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.buttonFoto);
        imgTakenPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.genomenFoto);

        btnTakePhoto.setOnClickListener(new btnTakePhotoClicker());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == CAM_REQUEST){
            setContentView(R.layout.share); //Change layout & display img in it
            Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
            imgTakenPhoto.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        }
    }

    class btnTakePhotoClicker implements Button.OnClickListener {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAM_REQUEST);
        }
    }
    //Share layout -- back button - Go back to first layout
    public void ibBackToPhotograph(View v) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have on both layout `share` and `activity_main` a `ImageView` with `id="@+id/genomenFoto"`

So after change layout with `setContentView` method you have to retrieve your `ImageView` from new layout. 2 `ImageView` with same id on 2 layout rare not the same `Object`

As this:

```
if(requestCode == CAM_REQUEST){
    setContentView(R.layout.share);
    Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    imgTakenPhoto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.genomenFoto);
    imgTakenPhoto.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
}
```